# Ansible read after write file operations in playbooks

Tags: file, shell, ansible

I am working on a project using Ansible which requires me to write some data to a file using one playbook and then read the data from the same file using another playbook.

The playbook will be something like this
test1.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
   - name: Writing data to test file
     local_action: shell echo "data:" {{ 100 |random(step=10) }} > test.txt
- include: test2.yml
```

and would need to read it using test2.yml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
   - test.txt
  tasks:
   - name: Writing data to test file
     local_action: shell echo "{{ data }}" >  result.txt
```

However,

The second playbook is not able to read the `latest` data being posted by the first playbook.

If I view the data written in `test.txt` and `result.txt` they both are different. Is there a way to achieve consistency between the results of playbook calls ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those two playbooks called separately? If they are included inside a master playbook, then this would explain it. All includes in the master playbook are resolved before execution, so Ansible would already have read both playbooks and the `vars_file` before any of them gets executed. You should be able to solve this by dynamically including the vars file during play with the [`include_vars`](http://docs.ansible.com/include_vars_module.html) module.

If I was wrong with my assumption and you're not including the playbooks in a parent playbook: What exactly do you mean by "different"? Is it completely different data or is it a formatting issue? I'm puzzled how data in general could not be consistent between calls. There is no magic in writing to and reading from a file. That should theoretically work.